# SQL:Check if the date is paid on time before following the return period

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

SQL: Check if the date is paid before the 19th of the month following the return period

The requirement is to determine OnTime Payment 'Y'/'N'

```
• If monthly = PAID before the 19th of the month following the return period
Example: Jan-Jan payment deadline = Feb 19
• If quarterly = paid before the 16th of the 2nd month following the return period
Example: Jan-Mar payment deadline = May 16
• If last quarterly = paid before the 30th of the month following the return period
Example: Oct-Dec payment deadline = Jan 30
```

For quarterly, if it is the last quarter then its paid 30th of the
following month, For rest of the quarter month, it is 16th of the month

```
with data as (
    select 'Sep-Sep2021' AS PERIOD,
           '2021-10-11 22:09:45' AS DT,
           'PAID' AS STATUS
    union all
    select 'Sep-Sep2021' AS PERIOD,
           '2021-10-20 22:09:45' AS DT,
           'PAID' AS STATUS
    union all
    select 'Jan-Mar2021'AS PERIOD,
           '2021-04-11 22:09:45'AS DT,
           'PAID'
    union all
    select 'Jan-Mar2021'AS PERIOD,
           '2021-05-20 22:09:45'AS DT,
           'PAID'
    union all
    select 'Jan-Jan2021'AS PERIOD,
           '2021-02-11 22:09:44'AS DT,
           'PAID'AS STATUS
    union all
    select 'Sep-Sep2021'AS PERIOD,
           '2021-10-12 04:10:00'AS DT,
           'CANCELLED'AS STATUS
    union all 
    select 'Jul-Sep2021'AS PERIOD,
           '2021-10-12 04:10:00'AS DT,
           'PAID' STATUS
    union all 
    select 'Oct-Dec2021'AS PERIOD,
           '2022-01-29 04:10:00'AS DT,
           'PAID STATUS
)
select * from data;
```

Expected Result

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited with author addition of *quaterly last*

```
select
    period,
    CASE
        WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(period,SUBSTR(period,1,3)) = 2 THEN 'monthly'
        WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(period,SUBSTR(period,1,3)) = 1 AND SUBSTR(period,1,3) = 'Oct' THEN 'quaterly_last'
        ELSE 'quaterly'
    END AS payment_type,
    CASE payment_type
        WHEN 'monthly' THEN DATEADD('month', 1, TO_DATE('19'||SUBSTR(period,5), 'DDMonYYYY'))
        WHEN 'quaterly' THEN DATEADD('month', 2, TO_DATE('16'||SUBSTR(period,5), 'DDMonYYYY'))
        WHEN 'quaterly_last' THEN DATEADD('month', 1, TO_DATE('30'||SUBSTR(period,5), 'DDMonYYYY'))
    END AS payment_deadline,
    dt,
    status,
    CASE
        WHEN status != 'PAID' THEN NULL
        WHEN dt < payment_deadline  THEN 'Y'
        WHEN dt >= payment_deadline THEN 'N'
    END AS on_time_payment
FROM data
```

[image]